# What does this line "render: h => h('Frame', [ h(App) ])" do?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nativescript-vue

I am trying to understand how NativeScript-Vue works. While most of the tutorial codes make sense to me, this particular line in the following page seems to evade me.

https://nativescript-vue.org/en/docs/elements/components/frame/

The render function in VueJS seems to have different meaning.
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html

```
new Vue({
  store,
  render: h => h('frame', [h(App)])
}).$start()
```

I believe I have missed something obvious. Still if possible, please explain this line to me.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out I did miss something, less than obvious though. It is a combination of arrow function and "h" standing for hyperscript. The following page I stumbled onto does a good job explaining everything in detail.

https://css-tricks.com/what-does-the-h-stand-for-in-vues-render-method/